# Airfoil plottin by data file without court line in Spyder by python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I use the AeroPython [codes](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/barbagroup/AeroPython/blob/master/lessons/10_Lesson10_sourcePanelMethod.ipynb) by Barba Group's;

```
#import libraries and modules needed
import os
import numpy
from scipy import integrate, linalg
from matplotlib import pyplot


# load geometry from data file
naca_filepath = os.path.join('resources', 'naca0012.dat')
with open(naca_filepath, 'r') as infile:
    x, y = numpy.loadtxt(infile, dtype=float, unpack=True)

# plot geometry
width = 10
pyplot.figure(figsize=(width, width))
pyplot.grid()
pyplot.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
pyplot.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)
pyplot.plot(x, y, color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
pyplot.axis('scaled', adjustable='box')
pyplot.xlim(-0.1, 1.1)
pyplot.ylim(-0.1, 0.1);
```

and use from airfoil.com [naca0012 data file](https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/n0012.dat)  (change the name "n0012.dat" to "naca0012.dat" and delete Tittle inside the file because the program don't use the strings in data file)

in the lesson look like figure like this

[image]

but I use the code plot this includes the courtline

[image]

Something wrong but what is it?

Answer (score 3):

The link to the airfoil database contains the coordinates of a NACA0012 in the Lednicer format, while the code in AeroPython Lesson was written for an airfoil in Selig's format.
(The [Notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/barbagroup/AeroPython/blob/master/lessons/10_Lesson10_sourcePanelMethod.ipynb) compute the flow around an airfoil using a source-panel method.)

**Selig's format** starts from the trailing edge of the airfoil, goes over the upper surface, then over the lower surface, to go back to the trailing edge.

**Lednicer's format** lists points on the upper surface (from leading edge to trailing edge), then points on the lower surface (from leading edge to trailing edge).

You can load the Selig's format (skipping the header "NACA 0012 AIRFOILS" with `skiprows=1` in `numpy.loadtxt`) as follow:

```py
import urllib


# Retrieve and save geometry to file.
selig_url = 'http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/seligdatfile?airfoil=n0012-il'
selig_path = 'naca0012-selig.dat'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(selig_url, selig_path)
# Load coordinates from file.
with open(selig_path, 'r') as infile:
    x1, y1 = numpy.loadtxt(infile, unpack=True, skiprows=1)
```

The NACA0012 airfoil here contains `131` points and you will see that the trailing edge has a finite thickness:

```py
print('Number of points:', x1.size)  # -> 131
print(f'First point: ({x1[0]}, {y1[0]})')  # -> (1.0, 0.00126)
print(f'Last point: ({x1[-1]}, {y1[-1]})')  # -> (1.0, -0.00126)
```

If you do the same with the Lednicer's format (with `skiprows=2` for the header), you will load `132` points (leading-edge point is duplicated) with points on the upper surface being flipped (from leading edge to trailing edge).
(That's why you observe this line in the middle with `pyplot.plot`; the line connects the trailing edge from the upper surface to the leading edge from the lower surface.)

One way to re-orient the points to follow Selig's format is to skip the leading edge on the upper surface (i.e., skip the duplicated point) and flip the points on the upper surface.
Here is a possible solution:

```py
import numpy


# Retrieve and save geometry to file.
lednicer_url = 'http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/lednicerdatfile?airfoil=n0012-il'
lednicer_path = 'naca0012-lednicer.dat'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(lednicer_url, lednicer_path)

# Load coordinates from file (re-orienting points in Selig format).
with open(lednicer_path, 'r') as infile:
    # Second line of the file contains the number of points on each surface.
    _, info = (next(infile) for _ in range(2))
    # Get number of points on upper surface (without the leading edge).
    num = int(info.split('.')[0]) - 1
    # Load coordinates, skipping the first point (leading edge on upper surface).
    x2, y2 = numpy.loadtxt(infile, unpack=True, skiprows=2)
    # Flip points on the upper surface.
    x2[:num], y2[:num] = numpy.flip(x2[:num]), numpy.flip(y2[:num])
```

You will end up with `131` points, oriented the same way as the Selig's format.

```py
print('Number of points:', x2.size)  # -> 131
print(f'First point: ({x2[0]}, {y2[0]})')  # -> (1.0, 0.00126)
print(f'Last point: ({x2[-1]}, {y2[-1]})')  # -> (1.0, -0.00126)
```

Finally, we can also checks that coordinates are the same with `numpy.allclose`:

```py
assert numpy.allclose(x1, x2, rtol=0.0, atol=1e-6)  # -> True
assert numpy.allclose(y1, y2, rtol=0.0, atol=1e-6)  # -> True
```